# Disable program back button after creating new intent

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and just starting with the basics following this guide

[Android Starting Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

The app allows the user to input a string and once the user clicks send, it takes you to a new intent displaying the message. Now at the bottom of the link where there are 2 pictures displayed, there is no visible back button, but on my emulator, the "My First App" is a button indicating it can go back. However, if I press it, it crashes the program. Is there anyway to disable the title message from being a button?

If I press the back button on the phone, the program works perfectly fine.

Comment: You are better of clarifying the question. Which back button are you referring to? Soft/hardware back button at the bottom or title in the ActionBar, "MyFirstApp"?

Comment: The button I am referring to is the "My First App" as displayed on the pictures of the bottom of the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think the title bar is just a regular view thats located in the android library rather than the `res` folder associated with your application. You should be able to find the title bar and disable clicks with the following:

```
View v = findViewById (android.R.id.title);
v.setClickable(false);
```

That should disable clicks on the title bar.

Comment: I tried putting this in the OnCreate function, but it isn't working. Where does this belong?

Answer (score 0):

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This is the line you are looking for. Mind you, it is commented appropriately, too.

Comment: getActionBar() is for the main activity. I created a new intent that does not have an actionbar. Regardless, if I set actionbar to false, it does not fix anything.